How to toggle the FLAG_SECURE in Tauri 2 mobile app
I am just getting familiar with developing mobile applications using the newly released Tauri 2. How can I enable or disable the FLAG_SECURE while using the application?
I would like to include an option in my app to turn it off, as some users might find it irritating that no workaround allows taking screenshots of the app in this mode.
